# Things Which Represent Other Things

Tags: rest, architecture

Let's say I want to hand out things which represent other things (pretend phone numbers) via REST. We can call the representations tickets.

The goal is to create a thing which represents another thing but does not reveal the content of the thing it represents. Let's pretend we're talking about phone numbers.

There is a choice here. One could create a ticket from random numbers and letters which are stored in the backend or one could calculate a ticket from the phone number.

PRO/CON of Ticket Creation:

- PRO: cannot be cracked
- PRO: you can expire a ticket - (why is this good?)
- CON: you have one ticket per requested phone number stored in a backend server

Pros and Cons of Calculation

- CON: A calculation can be cracked and reveal the original content.
- CON: calculation mechanism cannot be changed - (true?)
- PRO: No backend storage required.
- PRO: A calculation is a REST lookup (GET) as opposed to a REST (POST)

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you're referring to the URI's (e.g. HTTP://domain.com/PhoneTicket/skjdfskdjfslkj) or as the contents of a GET/POST/... request?

Comment: I've found that using a lightweight encryption algorithm works very well in these cases. Can't be cracked easily, is always unique, and doesn't require a backend storage. Also, a major plus is that it's two-way, meaning that you don't have to store hashes for all entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of "*representation ticket*" as a **Hash** for a phone number. When you think of it this way, you'll lean towards **Calculation**, and you will also draw from a vast knowledge base of hashing.

Comment: Especially when you consider cryptographic hashes